# setNeedsDisplay doesn't work on subclass of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
class CustomView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        print("Draw")
    }
}
```

Drag a UIView, set its class to be `CustomView`, create a reference `customView` to it.

When I call `customView.setNeedsDisplay()`, `drawRect` of `CustomView` get called.

```
import UIKit
class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        print("DrawImage")
    }
}
```

Drag a UIImageView, set its class to be `CustomImageView`, create a reference `customImageView` to it.

When I call `customImageView.setNeedsdisplay()`, nothing happen. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display. UIImageView does not call the drawRect: method of its subclasses. If your subclass needs to include custom drawing code, you should subclass the UIView class instead.